# Find the constant $C$ such that the following is a p.d.f.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

> Find the constant $C>0$ such that $C\dfrac{\sqrt{xy}}{x^2+y^2}$ is a pdf on the region $0<x,y;xy\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$

I have been stuck with this problem for quite some days. I tried routine integration for a long time but got to nowhere. I believe some clever transformation is going to be used on $X$ and $Y$, but I do not know what they are.

The thing I noted is that the pdf is highly symmetric, but I realized this observation leads me to nowhere. I would like some help.

Comment: Did you try a switch to polar coordinates?

Comment: How can I? For that we would need something like $x^2+y^2\leq r^2$. Also I am not a pro at switching to polar coordinates. Are you advising $x=r\sin\theta$ and $y=r\cos\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to polar coordinates, one obtains
$$1=C\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta} \,dr \, d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}C\int_0^{\pi/4}d\theta$$
So $C=4\sqrt{2}/\pi$.

Comment: The upper limit for the integral with respect to $r$ is incorrect. $x\,y=1/2$ becomes $r=1/\sqrt{2\cos\theta\sin\theta}$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: In particular, this makes computations even easier.

Comment: I understood nothing what happened here. Sorry but I do not know how to convert to polar coordinates. So you took $x=r\sin\theta$ and $y=r\cos\theta$ then how can you write $dxdy/r$ as $d\theta dr$?

Comment: I read the limits as x,y<1/2.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @LandonCarter, yes.

Comment: I want to ask,Paul, how did you know Polar Coordinates would work? Why didn't you try the traditional method? If you used that you would find the inner integral can be evaluated but the outer integral is the hard one.

Comment: @LandonCarter, whenever I see $x^2+y^2$ I start thinking polar coordinates, even if other factors indicate possible otherwise.  The fact that the curve $xy=1/2$ adds a factor which cancels out other complications make it look like a good one to try.